How did Paul understand when Chani didn't translate completely?
Chani translates the conversation between Stilgar and a  Young Fremen
Patrol, who are speaking in the Chakobsa language:

Chani: He's asking why we're so late. He thinks you're spies. He
said...
Paul: I got that.

How did Paul understand when Chani didn't translate completely?

Why are you asking all these random questions? Obviously he knows enough of the language to understand what was said.

@DanielRoseman - It's obvious that he's watching (and enjoying) the film Dune and wanting to understand clearly what's happening. That's to be applauded.

Could you cite the origin of the quote exactly.

@JiminyCricket. - It's from Dune, Part 2. when Paul arrives at Sietch Tabr.

Fair enough, but I was hoping to encourage the OP to get into the habit of adding more specific information to their questions. @Valorum

@JiminyCricket. - The question is clearly tagged and a two-second glance at the transcript shows where the line is said in the film; https://scrapsfromtheloft.com/movies/dune-part-two-2024-transcript/

Well, yes, but it's a misquote and lacks the "details and context" that the [ask] section of the [help] requires. I'm not here to be pedantic, just to encourage the OP to add sufficient details to the question. @Valorum

@JiminyCricket. - It's not a misquote. It's completely accurate, albeit missing the bit that's spoken [in subtitles].

@Valorum I don't know why you've taken to babysit this lost cause, because, while nothing is technically breaking any rule (I must clarify because we got into this before), there's nothing to be applauded here. This is a user who is not facing ESL, but "minimum effort at comprehension" issues, jumping to the internet in search of answers before finishing the scene he's asking about. We know this because he's asked questions about things answered in the following few sentences. This is an attention deficit problem, not something warranting applause.

(As an aside, I know nobody made me the arbiter of good questions or anything, but none of his questions are good. In fact, the community agrees they are low quality, given that they almost unfailingly earn more downvotes than upvotes.)

Paul isn't an expert in Chakobsa, but it doesn't take a linguist to determine that the line was "You're not welcome". The guard looks him right in the eye and seems angry.
Paul has a little smile on his face when he says...

"I got that".

...to Chani. He's keen to indicate that while he doesn't speak their language, he's not a fool and he's not a child.

